# Align items within a div?

Tags: css, html, alignment, items

I am trying to stay away from tables because I am told they are to be used for tabular data only. However, I am confused as to how to implement this functionality. My navigation bar has a search button, register link, login link, and two dividers. How would one align each item within the div much like one can with tables? Please excuse my newbieness to CSS =P

Comment: Possible duplicate.  Check out this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827683/side-by-side-list-items-as-icons-within-a-div-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul class="menu">
 <li>Link 1</li>
 <li>Link 2</li>
 <li>Link 3</li>
 <li>Link 4</li>
</ul>

<style type="text/css">
   .menu {margin:0px;padding:0px;list-style:none;width:600px;margin:auto}
   .menu li {display:inline;padding:5px;margin-right:10px;background-color:#333;color:#fff}
</style>
```

Although I have not tested it, this should give you something you are looking for. Experiment on the above code to fine tune to your requirements. And yeah tables need not be avoided all the time. For displaying tabular data, tables are the best option

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried this suggestion but unfortunately all items are still not centered.

[Here's a screenshot showing the problem](http://i.imgur.com/cYYaL.png)

Comment: Have edited the code. Specify a width and then margin:auto. This will center it for the width specified.

Comment: Thanks this works great! However, is there any way to now center them all horizontally as well? Currently the items start at the position 0 rather than aligning to the middle.

Comment: The code I specified centers them horizontally. I'm assuming the width of your menu is 600px. That block of 600px will be centered in the parent object. Try experimenting this code in a blank html file. Its centering it horizontally for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a newbie, try this tool.
http://accessify.com/tools-and-wizards/developer-tools/list-o-matic/